# Unable to add string to an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, sqlite

I am trying to make a column in my Posts table which is an array. I want the array to store the current_user's email (or id/name etc...).

However, for some reason I cannot get the current_user's email to append to the array.

The array column is called claimed_users and the purpose of the column is to store the user_email of all users who have "claimed" the post. This way I can implement code to prevent them from claiming more than one post amongst other things.

I currently have this in my View:

```
<%= link_to "Claim This Post", { controller: :posts, action: :claim, post_id: @post.id, user_id: current_user.id },{ class: 'btn btn-default'} %>
```

And This for my action in PostsController:

```
def claim
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])

  @post.increment!(:claim)
  @post.claimed_users << current_user.id
  if @post.claim < 99
    redirect_to @post, notice: 'You have successfully claimed this post. You     have 8 hours to post a response'
  else
    redirect_to @post, notice: 'Sorry, this post already has enough claims'
  end
end
```

I added "serialize: claimed_users, Array" in my Posts model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :responses
  has_many :top_responses
  has_many :claims
  serialize :claimed_users, Array
end
```

However, I still have no luck. When I look in the database using the Rails console I still get "claimed_users: nil".

Before, I was getting "claimed_users: "--- []\n"" but that changed when I added some code though I'm not exactly sure where as I have tried a lot of things so far and read a lot of SO questions and google results to no avail.

I explored the idea of creating a new Model/Controller for Claims/Claimed_Users but it doesn't make much sense when I think about it.

Any help is greatly appreciated! I'm still fairly new to programming.

Comment: (1) You really should indent your code so that humans can read it. (2) You're not calling `save` anywhere.

Comment: Thanks @sa77 and @mu is too short. When I add `@post.claimed_users.save` after `@post.claimed_users << current_user.id `, I'm getting the error "undefined method `save' for [1]:Array". 1 is the user.id in this case.

Comment: Also the fact that the error message has [1] implies that the current_user.id is getting added to the claimed_users array, correct? So why does it show nil in the rails console?

Comment: What error message? And just because something has been added to a local array doesn't mean that it has been added to the database, hence the `save` method.

Comment: @mus is too short the error message I get when using the save method is: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 7ms (ActiveRecord: 2.6ms)
NoMethodError (undefined method 'save' for [1]:Array):
app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:81:in 'claim'

Comment: Maybe because save method can't be called without create method already existing? But then this would require its own model and controller, correct?

Comment: What about `@post.save`?

Comment: Wow @mu is too short thank you very much! It now shows in the console (although in a slightly strange format "1\n-"). I also tried adding the user email and it worked. Such a simple oversight by me. Thanks again.

Comment: BTW, the odd looking string you're seeing is [YAML](http://yaml.org), that's what `serialize` does to the data you give it. Accessing YAML inside the database (say in a WHERE clause) is a complete nightmare, that's why you should pretend that `serialize` doesn't exist.